# Image conversion generate exception

Tags: c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I need record from three tables i wrote sql query for this.but on front end when i assign values to textbox and picture box.excption is genrated.

> Source : System.Drawing Message : Parameter is not valid.Method :
>   System.Drawing.Image FromStream(System.IO.Stream, Boolean, Boolean)
>   Stack Trace :
>
> at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean
>   useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)    at
>   System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream).

My sql query is

```
select s.Name,s.FatherName,CAST(s.Picture as varbinary)as picture,s.Description,SUM(l.Amount) as Loan,SUM(p.Amount) as Paid from Staff s 
left outer join Loan l on s.StaffID=l.StaffID left outer join Payment p on l.StaffID=p.StaffID where s.StaffID=17 group by s.Name,s.FatherName,Description,CAST(Picture as varbinary)
```

Comment: My guess is you're passing it a byte array and not a memory stream. That's just based on your sql statement. If you put some code up that might help us.